# How to write/append 2 columns into a .txt file Using Python?

Tags: python, list, loops, text

i am new in programing i am working in a small project i am getting problem with this:

I want to append 2 different columns in one .txt file.

```
def write_file_content(file_name_to_write):
    container=[]
    date=get_current_date()
    time=get_current_time()
    container.append(date)
    container.append(time)

  with open(get_EveryDayTrans_folder_path()+file_name_to_write+".txt","a") as edit_file:
        for nm in range(1,11):
            edit_file.write('%s.\n'%nm)
        for item in container:
            edit_file.write('%s\n' %item)
```

with this code i am getting following output :
1.
2.
3.
4.
5.
6.
7.
8.
9.
10.
01-29-2019
10:40 PM

but i want get the output like this:

1. 01-29-2019
2. 10:40 PM

3.

4.

5.

6.

7.

8.

9.

10.

Comment: What platform are you on? New line characters on Windows and MacOS need to be `\r\n`, not just `\n`, which would explain the lack of new lines in your file.

Comment: i am using windows and now just change it but it is stil the same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with your code that need to be fixed:

1. You are using two loops, one then the other, to print to your file. You need to combine these loops so that you can know the number and the item you want to print in the same loop iteration. You only get one chance* to print a line correctly, so you need everything that needs to be on that line ready to go.
2. You are writing a new-line character after the number you want in front. This is preventing you from writing more text on the same line. Instead, print all of the data formatted together in one write() call with `\r\n` at the end.

```python
with open(get_EveryDayTrans_folder_path()+file_name_to_write+".txt","a") as edit_file:
    nm = 1
    for item in container:
        edit_file.write('%s. %s\r\n' % (nm, item))
        nm += 1
```

*Only one chance unless you go back and edit the line in the file again.

Comment: Thank you very much it is working perfectly just need to change the iterator varibale name nm +=1

Answer (score 1):

There's a very handy python function named **zip**
It takes two iterables ( = list and similar stuff) and returns tuples where each tuple contains one element of both. Well, kind of like a zip.
It is very often used to iterate over two lists in parallel.
In your case this would be:

> for nm, item  in zip(range(1,11), container):

and then you can just print nm and item
I'm not so familiar with the %s style, so I would just write:

> edit_file.write("{} {}".format(nm, item))

or if you use python 3.6 or so:

> edit_file.write(f"{nm} {item}")

Hope that helps!

p.s.:
I just saw that your second column only has two items. The zip function stops when the *shorter* iterable is exhausted. In your case you might want the opposite. For that there is **zip_longest** from the itertools module:

> from itertools import zip_longest
>   for nm, item  in zip_longest(range(1,11), container, fillvalue=""):

This will return:

nm, item = (0, container[0])

nm, item = (1, container[1])

nm, item = (2, "")

nm, item = (3, "")

etc.